# Multiple actions were found that match the request in mvc5 api application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

When I try to hit my API controller using get url I am getting following error:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request:
>
> IsStoreKeyValid on type BlexzWeb.Controllers.ApiDevToolController
> GetPageIds on type BlexzWeb.Controllers.ApiDevToolController

The WebApiConfig.cs are like bellow:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //code bellow used to return json on api call
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings
            .Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.RequestHeaderMapping("Accept",
                 "text/html",
                 StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase,
                 true,
                 "application/json"));
    }
}
```

Controller code:

```
public class ApiDevToolController : ApiController
{
    private bool IsValid { get; set; }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult IsStoreKeyValid(string storeName, string storeKey)
    {
    }

    //get list of pageids
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPageIds(string storeName, string storeKey)
    {
    }
}
```

Url I am using to hit controller: `http://localhost:49817/api/apidevtool/isstorekeyvalid?storeName=test.myblexz.com&storeKey=fdesfhkfg5g437dfgh5u`

Whats wrong I am doing here? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Could you show us your `ApiDevToolController `code?

Comment: added controller code

Comment: OK thanks could you show us your execute url?

Comment: i have added url also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because your second action name starts with Get... and also it has the same parameter like first action (IsStoreKeyValid(string storeName, string storeKey))

By default, if action is HttpGet then it searches action name which starts with GetSomething
and check parameter. More Info [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection)

You need to change the second function name or need to use attribute routing

ex.[Route("pageIds")]

more info [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Answer (score 1):

Let us see the source code from [webapi ApiControllerActionSelector](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/749384689e027a2fcd29eb79a9137b94cea611a8/src/System.Web.Http/Controllers/ApiControllerActionSelector.cs) code of action  selector.

```
private List<CandidateActionWithParams> FindMatchingActions(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, bool ignoreVerbs = false)
{
    // If matched with direct route?
    IHttpRouteData routeData = controllerContext.RouteData;
    IEnumerable<IHttpRouteData> subRoutes = routeData.GetSubRoutes();

    IEnumerable<CandidateActionWithParams> actionsWithParameters = (subRoutes == null) ? 
        GetInitialCandidateWithParameterListForRegularRoutes(controllerContext, ignoreVerbs) :
        GetInitialCandidateWithParameterListForDirectRoutes(controllerContext, subRoutes, ignoreVerbs);

    // Make sure the action parameter matches the route and query parameters.
    List<CandidateActionWithParams> actionsFoundByParams = FindActionMatchRequiredRouteAndQueryParameters(actionsWithParameters);

    List<CandidateActionWithParams> orderCandidates = RunOrderFilter(actionsFoundByParams);
    List<CandidateActionWithParams> precedenceCandidates = RunPrecedenceFilter(orderCandidates);

    // Overload resolution logic is applied when needed.
    List<CandidateActionWithParams> selectedCandidates = FindActionMatchMostRouteAndQueryParameters(precedenceCandidates);

    return selectedCandidates;
}
```

We can see if you use register in route for `RouteTable`, it will find the execute action by your parameters type by defualt.

I would use `RoutePrefix` and `Route` attribute to set the route config for web api.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/ApiDevTool")]
public class ApiDevToolController : ApiController
{
    private bool IsValid { get; set; }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("IsStoreKeyValid")]
    public string IsStoreKeyValid(string storeName, string storeKey)
    {

    }

    //get list of pageids
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetPageIds")]
    public string GetPageIds(string storeName, string storeKey)
    {

    }
}
```